# JPA, duplicate entry on persist in join table when using @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink, duplicates

I want to create custom JAAS authentication where my users and principals relationships are defined in JPA as shown:

**class AuthUser**

```
public class AuthUser implements Serializable {

    // own properties
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int uid;

    @Column(name="NAME",unique=true)
    private String name;

    // Join classes
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade={CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="PRINCIPALS_PRINCIPAL")
    private Set<AuthPrincipal> principals;
}
```

**class AuthPrincipal**

```
public class AuthPrincipal implements Serializable {

    // Defining roles
    public enum Principal {
        AUTHUSER, STUDENT, ADMINISTRATOR, TEACHER
    }

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="PRINCIPAL")
    private Principal principal;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "principals")
    @JoinColumn(name="USERS_USER")
    private Set<AuthUser> users;
}
```

**Maps to the following Table definition**

```
Table authprincipal
===================
PRINCIPAL        varchar(255) PK

Table authuser
==============
UID              int(11)      PK
EMAIL            varchar(255)
NAME             varchar(255)
PASSWORD         varchar(255)

Table authuser_authprincipal
============================
users_UID            int(11)      PK
principals_PRINCIPAL varchar(255) PK
```

Now, I created a JSF file from which I call an action method that calls this one:

```
    public void createUser(AuthUser newUser) throws UserNameExistsException, UserEmailExistsException {
    AuthPrincipal role = authRoleFacade.find(AuthPrincipal.Principal.AUTHUSER);
    if( role == null ){
        role = new AuthPrincipal();
        role.setPrincipal(AuthPrincipal.Principal.AUTHUSER);
        authRoleFacade.create(role);
    }    
    authUserFacade.create(newUser);
    addPrincipalToUser(newUser, role);
}
```

**The actual problem**
I can create the first user. But I can't create the second user . Notice that at the second user I use the existing role object, and only cascade a merge operation.

The strangest thing is that it says it duplicates the 2-AUTHUSER key where 2 is the id of the new user so cannot already be in the database. What is wrong with it or with Eclipselink or with Me?

*The error what eclipselink throws*

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2-AUTHUSER' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO AUTHUSER_AUTHPRINCIPAL (principals_PRINCIPAL, users_UID) VALUES (?, ?)
        bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="principals" sql="INSERT INTO AUTHUSER_AUTHPRINCIPAL (principals_PRINCIPAL, users_UID) VALUES (?, ?)")
```

Comment: Was my fault, ... posting the answer of my question right now.

Answer (score 2):

This was all My fault. I was not careful enough :)

1) The problem occured because of my fault, though, I don't know why the error log talked about user id 2 when I only had one user, but i'm gonna tell a possible reason

**The problem was:** I wanted to persist an already persisted user. In my `@SessionScoped` `@ManagedBean` I created an `AuthUser` in the constructor. In the first registration it got persisted but I did not create a fresh one. When I wanted to register the next one what my program actually did was: changed the username, email and password of the already persisted AuthUser and wanted to persist it again.

Back to 1) I can imagine when I called persist the second time, Eclipselink actually persisted my Entity updating the user id to 2 in both the `AuthUser` table and the join table. Afterwards because I defined the Merge operation on `AuthUser.principals`, it wanted to update again the join table and that's when it messed up. If I had looked closely to the generated Queries in the log file, I think I could have figured it out myself.

I got the hint here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/692056/#msg_692056